# Python while loop not reverting to original value when repeating itself

Tags: python, while-loop

Here is my code:

```
import math
flag_acc = True
n_tri = 8
r = 1
error = 1
while flag_acc:
     accuracy_desired = float(input('To what accuracy would you like pi? (enter number of decimal places desired)'))
    acc_des = 1/(10**accuracy_desired)
    while error > acc_des:
        theta_deg = 360/n_tri
        theta_rad = math.radians(theta_deg)
        c = math.sqrt(2 - 2*math.cos(theta_rad))
        circum = c*n_tri
        pie = circum/2
        n_tri += 1
        error = ((math.pi -pie)/math.pi)
    print('Accuracy desired was: %0.3e'%(acc_des))
    print('The number of triangles used to meet the desired accuracy was: ',n_tri)
    print('Estimate for pi based on number of triangles is: ', pie)
    repeat = input('Would you like to repeat with a new precision? (y/n)')
    if repeat in ['n', 'N']:
        flag_acc = False
```

My problem is that every time I respond yes to 'repeat' the n_tri value can only increase, even when my new accuracy_desired value has decreased.

I have tried defining n_tri in multiple different places within my code (inside both while loops, and before the while loops as it is now), and in if statements throughout

Comment: The way you have set up your code, n_tri can only be reset to 8 (`n_tri = 8`) or increase by one (`n_tri +=1`). And it is only initialised to 8 once at beginning. After that, it will only ever increase. Nowhere do you have code `n_tri -= 1` to reduce its value. If you want to decrement t when accuracy_desired is decreased, you have to introduce code to compare to current accuracy and then decide whether to add 1 or decrease 1

Comment: I don't understand your question. You only ever increase it. It is never reset inside the while loop. So what do you expect?

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing but try setting n_tri to a starter value after you get input in the first while loop

Answer (score 0):

keep a tag of old accuracy and new accuracy desired and last n_tri

check and increase or decrease the value of n_tri .. from the second time.

```
import math
flag_acc = True
n_tri = 8
r = 1
error = 1
old_acc=None
while flag_acc:
    accuracy_desired = float(input('To what accuracy would you like pi? (enter number of decimal places desired)'))
    if not old_acc and accuracy_desired<old_acc:
        n_tri=last_tri-2 # n_tri will be one more thane
    acc_des = 1/(10**accuracy_desired)
    last_tri=n_tri
    while error > acc_des:
        theta_deg = 360/n_tri
        theta_rad = math.radians(theta_deg)
        c = math.sqrt(2 - 2*math.cos(theta_rad))
        circum = c*n_tri
        pie = circum/2
        n_tri += 1
        error = ((math.pi -pie)/math.pi)
    old_acc=accuracy_desired
    print('Accuracy desired was: %0.3e'%(acc_des))
    print('The number of triangles used to meet the desired accuracy was: ',n_tri)
    print('Estimate for pi based on number of triangles is: ', pie)
    repeat = input('Would you like to repeat with a new precision? (y/n)')
    if repeat in ['n', 'N']:
        flag_acc = False
```